# Edge is no longer in the background apps list

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Ever since it was introduced, I have loved the ability to prevent some of my apps from running in the background. I have used it to stop Edge from playing music when I lock my computer or just minimize Edge.

Microsoft first defaulted to disabled. Then they forced the setting on, probably because people had been complaining. Now, it's not even in the list. And the list is way shorter than it used to be.

How can I prevent Edge from running in the background? I would very much love to be able to pause everything it's doing by simply minimizing the window or locking the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to disable it by the register editor.

1. run cmd.exe as administrator
2. run regedit
3. find the register path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\BackgroundAccessApplications
4. you can see key **Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe** (or something like this)
5. double click **Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe**
6. modify the **Disabled** to 1, if there is no such setting, just create it to disable it to be as background app.
   Name: Disabled
   Type: REG_DWORD
   Value Data: 1

If there is no **Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe** in the **BackgroundAccessApplications**, create it by right-click the **BackgroundAccessApplications** and create new Key, they change the key name as **Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe**.

In addition, if you also have the setting **DisabledByUser**, remember modify it as 1, too. If you don't have just modify the **Disabled**.

[image]

Comment: Oh my. That was crazy. I wonder how and why the BackgroundAccessApplications got cleaned out. The key wasn't there. After adding it as per your walkthrough, I can once again enjoy "minimize to pause" - and without restarting anything, too :) Thank you very much!

Comment: What's worse, after I rebooted my computer today, the key was gone. Do you have any ideas? I'm on a domain btw.

Comment: It sounds like the Domain configuration affects your PC, can you temporarily exit the domain, and reboot again to see if the register still disappears? Or did you get any message about this? Or just run gpresult /h C:\result.html to check the group policy from domain.