# Microsoft edge not appear in background apps

Tags: microsoft-edge, spotlight, background

I want to fix windows spotlight, but, when i was triying to solve the problem checking what aplications were in background i didn´t see microsoft edge. Does anyone knows why that app is not there ?

There is a [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1344415/edge-is-no-longer-in-the-background-apps-list/1643163?noredirect=1#comment2511100_1643163)  where is commented but i tried those things and i´m in the initial point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow harrymc's recommendation, as that should completely resolve your problem. Just to add that if it's not ticked on in windows settings, it won't show in the background either.

Windows settings -> Privacy -> Background apps.

Make sure that's on an Microsoft Edge is on the list and ticked on.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1344649/8672)
that you linked,
Microsoft Edge will stay in the background if it's running an application/webpage
that can issue notifications.

To enable:

- Click the three dots menu and choose "Settings"
- On the Settings page click "System" on the left
- On the System page, turn on
  "Continue running background apps when Microsoft Edge is closed"

Comment: Okey, i´m gonna try that. I  didn´t see this option before. Thanks a lot.